# How to make this XSLT elimination transformation works exclusively for different node parents?

Tags: xml, xslt

**The XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[*][deep-equal(.,preceding::*[name()=current()/name()][@id=current()/@id][1])]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied to my input:**

```
<myroot>
    <nodeA id="a">
        <section id="i">  
            <item1 id="0" method="create"> 
                <somechild>a</somechild>
            </item1>

            <item1 id="1" method="create">
                <otherchild>a</otherchild>
            </item1>
        </section>        

        <section id="i">
            <item1 id="0" method="create"> <!-- second consecutive create, we will remove this -->
                <somechild>a</somechild>
            </item1>
            <item1 id="0" method="create"> <!-- third consecutive create, BUT children have different value , so we don't remove this -->
                <somechild>bbb</somechild>
            </item1>
            <item1 id="3" method="create">
                <other>xx</other>    
            </item1>

            <item1 id="0" method="change"> 
                <otherchild>a</otherchild>
            </item1>
            <item1 id="0" method="change"> <!-- second consecutive create, we will remove this -->
                <otherchild>a</otherchild>
            </item1>
        </section>
    </nodeA>
</myroot>
```

**give me correct output:**

```
<myroot>
    <nodeA id="a">
        <section id="i">  
            <item1 id="0" method="create"> 
                <somechild>a</somechild>
            </item1>

            <item1 id="1" method="create">
                <otherchild>a</otherchild>
            </item1>
        </section>        

        <section id="i">
            <item1 id="0" method="create"> <!-- third consecutive create, BUT children have different value , so we don't remove this -->
                <somechild>bbb</somechild>
            </item1>
            <item1 id="3" method="create">
                <other>xx</other>    
            </item1>

            <item1 id="0" method="change"> 
                <otherchild>a</otherchild>
            </item1>
        </section>
    </nodeA>
</myroot>
```

**But the problem is when I have another `nodeA` with different `id` it treats those two nodes as one **

**Second Input example:**

```
<myroot>
    <nodeA id="a">
        <section id="i">  
            <item1 id="0" method="create"> 
                <somechild>a</somechild>
            </item1>

            <item1 id="1" method="create">
                <otherchild>a</otherchild>
            </item1>
        </section>        

        <section id="i">
            <item1 id="0" method="create"> <!-- second consecutive create, we will remove this -->
                <somechild>a</somechild>
            </item1>
            <item1 id="0" method="create"> <!-- third consecutive create, BUT children have different value , so we don't remove this -->
                <somechild>bbb</somechild>
            </item1>
            <item1 id="3" method="create">
                <other>xx</other>    
            </item1>

            <item1 id="0" method="change"> 
                <otherchild>a</otherchild>
            </item1>
            <item1 id="0" method="change"> <!-- second consecutive create, we will remove this -->
                <otherchild>a</otherchild>
            </item1>
        </section>
    </nodeA>

    <nodeA id="b">
        <section id="i">  
            <item1 id="0" method="create"> 
                <somechild>a</somechild>
            </item1>

            <item1 id="1" method="create">
                <otherchild>a</otherchild>
            </item1>
        </section>        

        <section id="i">
            <item1 id="0" method="create"> <!-- second consecutive create, we will remove this -->
                <somechild>a</somechild>
            </item1>
            <item1 id="0" method="create"> <!-- third consecutive create, BUT children have different value , so we don't remove this -->
                <somechild>bbb</somechild>
            </item1>
            <item1 id="3" method="create">
                <other>xx</other>    
            </item1>

            <item1 id="0" method="change"> 
                <otherchild>a</otherchild>
            </item1>
            <item1 id="0" method="change"> <!-- second consecutive create, we will remove this -->
                <otherchild>a</otherchild>
            </item1>
        </section>
    </nodeA>
</myroot>
```

**My output:**

```
<myroot>
   <nodeA id="a">
      <section id="i">
         <item1 id="0" method="create">
            <somechild>a</somechild>
         </item1>
         <item1 id="1" method="create">
            <otherchild>a</otherchild>
         </item1>
      </section>
      <section id="i">
         <item1 id="0" method="create"><!-- third consecutive create, BUT children have different value , so we don't remove this --><somechild>bbb</somechild>
         </item1>
         <item1 id="3" method="create">
            <other>xx</other>
         </item1>
         <item1 id="0" method="change">
            <otherchild>a</otherchild>
         </item1>
      </section>
   </nodeA>
   <nodeA id="b">
      <section id="i">
         <item1 id="0" method="create">
            <somechild>a</somechild>
         </item1>
      </section>
      <section id="i">
         <item1 id="0" method="create"><!-- third consecutive create, BUT children have different value , so we don't remove this --><somechild>bbb</somechild>
         </item1>
         <item1 id="0" method="change">
            <otherchild>a</otherchild>
         </item1>
      </section>
   </nodeA>
</myroot>
```

**Where the Expected Output should be:**

```
<myroot>
    <nodeA id="a">
        <section id="i">  
            <item1 id="0" method="create"> 
                <somechild>a</somechild>
            </item1>

            <item1 id="1" method="create">
                <otherchild>a</otherchild>
            </item1>
        </section>        

        <section id="i">
            <item1 id="0" method="create"> <!-- third consecutive create, BUT children have different value , so we don't remove this -->
                <somechild>bbb</somechild>
            </item1>
            <item1 id="3" method="create">
                <other>xx</other>    
            </item1>

            <item1 id="0" method="change"> 
                <otherchild>a</otherchild>
            </item1>
        </section>
    </nodeA>

    <nodeA id="b">
        <section id="i">  
            <item1 id="0" method="create"> 
                <somechild>a</somechild>
            </item1>

            <item1 id="1" method="create">
                <otherchild>a</otherchild>
            </item1>
        </section>        

        <section id="i">
            <item1 id="0" method="create"> <!-- third consecutive create, BUT children have different value , so we don't remove this -->
                <somechild>bbb</somechild>
            </item1>
            <item1 id="3" method="create">
                <other>xx</other>    
            </item1>

            <item1 id="0" method="change"> 
                <otherchild>a</otherchild>
            </item1>
        </section>
    </nodeA>
</myroot>
```

What should I add on the XSLT file to make it works for two or more node parent `nodeA` or `nodeB` etc.

- The objective is to remove node with `successive duplicate` with the
  same element name `item1` `item2` etc, same `id` and same `method`.
- An XML node followed by other node with exact `same element name`, `same
  id`, `same method` and `same children` will be considered duplicate.
- if the two nodes being compared did not share the same 'nodeA' level
  node, then they should not be considered as duplicates to be removed

Thanks
John

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "...works for different node parent...". Can you supply some sample document which is **NOT** transformed as you would like it by your current style-sheet?

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin Hi, I have supplied the example it is under the " Multiplied input example: along with the expected output" if you see there is `<nodeA id="a">` and `<nodeA id="b">` those are what I mean by multiple parents. Thank you.

Comment: @John: I have a solution which implements *exactly* your stated requirements and the output is different from the specified wanted output. This means that your question is self contradictory. Please, correct.

Comment: @John: Now that I *guessed* what you were unsuccessfully trying to define as the problem (not what you stated -- which contradicts with the provided wanted result), I get the wanted result -- see my answer. So the actual problem is your inability to define the problem -- you need to work hard in this area.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Maybe i should re-arrange the question like that (see updated) Thank you for your help.

Comment: @John: No, Say exactly: Duplicates are any two nodes that have the same `Nodexxx` common ancestor and ...

Answer (score 3):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
   "section/*
      [for $current in .,
           $curNodeAnc in $current/ancestor::*[starts-with(name(), 'node')][1]
         return
           some $preceding in $current/preceding::*
              satisfies
                 $preceding/parent::section
                and
                 $curNodeAnc is $preceding/ancestor::*[starts-with(name(), 'node')][1]
                and
                 deep-equal($current, $preceding)

      ]
   "/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<myroot>
        <nodeA id="a">
            <section id="i">
                <item1 id="0" method="create">
                    <somechild>a</somechild>
                </item1>

                <item1 id="1" method="create">
                    <otherchild>a</otherchild>
                </item1>
            </section>

            <section id="i">
                <item1 id="0" method="create"> <!-- second consecutive create, we will remove this -->
                    <somechild>a</somechild>
                </item1>
                <item1 id="0" method="create"> <!-- third consecutive create, BUT children have different value , so we don't remove this -->
                    <somechild>bbb</somechild>
                </item1>
                <item1 id="3" method="create">
                    <other>xx</other>
                </item1>

                <item1 id="0" method="change">
                    <otherchild>a</otherchild>
                </item1>
                <item1 id="0" method="change"> <!-- second consecutive create, we will remove this -->
                    <otherchild>a</otherchild>
                </item1>
            </section>
        </nodeA>

        <nodeA id="b">
            <section id="i">
                <item1 id="0" method="create">
                    <somechild>a</somechild>
                </item1>

                <item1 id="1" method="create">
                    <otherchild>a</otherchild>
                </item1>
            </section>

            <section id="i">
                <item1 id="0" method="create"> <!-- second consecutive create, we will remove this -->
                    <somechild>a</somechild>
                </item1>
                <item1 id="0" method="create"> <!-- third consecutive create, BUT children have different value , so we don't remove this -->
                    <somechild>bbb</somechild>
                </item1>
                <item1 id="3" method="create">
                    <other>xx</other>
                </item1>

                <item1 id="0" method="change">
                    <otherchild>a</otherchild>
                </item1>
                <item1 id="0" method="change"> <!-- second consecutive create, we will remove this -->
                    <otherchild>a</otherchild>
                </item1>
            </section>
        </nodeA>
</myroot>
```

**produces exactly the wanted result, though the requirements are badly defined and actually contradict the wanted result -- obviously John has a large space for improvement in this**:

```
<myroot>
   <nodeA id="a">
      <section id="i">
         <item1 id="0" method="create">
            <somechild>a</somechild>
         </item1>
         <item1 id="1" method="create">
            <otherchild>a</otherchild>
         </item1>
      </section>
      <section id="i">
         <item1 id="0" method="create"><!-- third consecutive create, BUT children have different value , so we don't remove this -->
         <somechild>bbb</somechild>
         </item1>
         <item1 id="3" method="create">
            <other>xx</other>
         </item1>
         <item1 id="0" method="change">
            <otherchild>a</otherchild>
         </item1>
      </section>
   </nodeA>
   <nodeA id="b">
      <section id="i">
         <item1 id="0" method="create">
            <somechild>a</somechild>
         </item1>
         <item1 id="1" method="create">
            <otherchild>a</otherchild>
         </item1>
      </section>
      <section id="i">
         <item1 id="0" method="create"><!-- third consecutive create, BUT children have different value , so we don't remove this -->
          <somechild>bbb</somechild>
         </item1>
         <item1 id="3" method="create">
            <other>xx</other>
         </item1>
         <item1 id="0" method="change">
            <otherchild>a</otherchild>
         </item1>
      </section>
   </nodeA>
</myroot>
```

Comment: Dimitre, I agree that requirements were badly defined. I got a different interpretation of the requirements. As I understood, his style-sheet was doing what he wanted it to do, EXCEPT that for the purposes of the deep-equal() comparison, the comparison was to be disallowed accross the the /myroot/NodeA boundary. In other words if the two nodes being compared did not share the same 'nodeA' level node, then they should not be considered as duplicates to be removed.

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin: Yes, this is what he *did not explain*.

Comment: Actually, I might have to take that back. It looks like we have identical output. Congradulations for first correct post.

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin what you're saying `if the two nodes being compared did not share the same 'nodeA' level node, then they should not be considered as duplicates to be removed` is exactly what I'm trying to say.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev I really thank you for your time to solve this problem. Thank you once again.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Hello, I just realized that the solutions does not take into accounts for the same sibling `section` with the same `id`. How to change it so that it will consider only `section` with the same `id` ? Thank you.

Comment: @John: The answer is: Ask a new question. And before doing that, please think it over well, because you have made such a track of almost identical questions, that nobody anymore would spend their time answering a question which is 99% the same as 99% of all questions they have seen (and answered) from you... :(

Comment: @John: I agree with Dimitre. Another thing you can do is come up with a bunch of small test cases to help explain the rules.

Comment: @John, this question was posted 10 days ago. Do you think it is about time to accept one answer?

Comment: You guys really need to understand, that sometimes requirements are very difficult to define 100% correctly the first time. It's very common for requirements to need refining after discovering cases that weren't thought of. @DimitreNovatchev, perhaps he wouldn't keep asking similar questions, if you didn't keep asking him to. Questions often need refining, this is a fact of life on SO. You really need to stop expecting new users to ask perfect questions the first time, every time. From http://stackoverflow.com/faq#etiquette: Be tolerant of others who may not know everything you know.

Comment: @Flynn1179: This is the *only* case we have of many tens of similar questions that are difficult to distinguish between each other. Given this fact, I think we have been *very* tolerant. And I hope that this particular user will learn to do better in this respect -- obviously he isn't paying much attention to this currently, because, repeating agai, he is *the only* user having shown such behavior.

Comment: @Flynn1179: To be more specific, of the total of 26 questions John has asked, 13 are about elimination or removal of nodes -- and all of them contain almost the same XML document and the same question.

Answer (score 1):

with this document as input document....

```
<myroot>
    <nodeA id="a">
        <section id="i">  
            <item1 id="0" method="create"> 
                <somechild>a</somechild>
            </item1>

            <item1 id="1" method="create">
                <otherchild>a</otherchild>
            </item1>
        </section>        

        <section id="i">
            <item1 id="0" method="create"> <!-- second consecutive create, we will remove this -->
                <somechild>a</somechild>
            </item1>
            <item1 id="0" method="create"> <!-- third consecutive create, BUT children have different value , so we don't remove this -->
                <somechild>bbb</somechild>
            </item1>
            <item1 id="3" method="create">
                <other>xx</other>    
            </item1>

            <item1 id="0" method="change"> 
                <otherchild>a</otherchild>
            </item1>
            <item1 id="0" method="change"> <!-- second consecutive create, we will remove this -->
                <otherchild>a</otherchild>
            </item1>
        </section>
    </nodeA>

    <nodeA id="b">
        <section id="i">  
            <item1 id="0" method="create"> 
                <somechild>a</somechild>
            </item1>

            <item1 id="1" method="create">
                <otherchild>a</otherchild>
            </item1>
        </section>        

        <section id="i">
            <item1 id="0" method="create"> <!-- second consecutive create, we will remove this -->
                <somechild>a</somechild>
            </item1>
            <item1 id="0" method="create"> <!-- third consecutive create, BUT children have different value , so we don't remove this -->
                <somechild>bbb</somechild>
            </item1>
            <item1 id="3" method="create">
                <other>xx</other>    
            </item1>

            <item1 id="0" method="change"> 
                <otherchild>a</otherchild>
            </item1>
            <item1 id="0" method="change"> <!-- second consecutive create, we will remove this -->
                <otherchild>a</otherchild>
            </item1>
        </section>
    </nodeA>
</myroot>
```

.. and this style-sheet ...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[*]
         [deep-equal(.,
           preceding::*[name()=current()/name()]
                       [@id = current()/@id]
                       [../../@id = current()/../../@id]
                       [1])]" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

... produces the stated required output ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<myroot>
   <nodeA id="a">
      <section id="i">
         <item1 id="0" method="create">
            <somechild>a</somechild>
         </item1>
         <item1 id="1" method="create">
            <otherchild>a</otherchild>
         </item1>
      </section>
      <section id="i">
         <item1 id="0" method="create"><!-- third consecutive create, BUT children have different value , so we don't remove this --><somechild>bbb</somechild>
         </item1>
         <item1 id="3" method="create">
            <other>xx</other>
         </item1>
         <item1 id="0" method="change">
            <otherchild>a</otherchild>
         </item1>
      </section>
   </nodeA>
   <nodeA id="b">
      <section id="i">
         <item1 id="0" method="create">
            <somechild>a</somechild>
         </item1>
         <item1 id="1" method="create">
            <otherchild>a</otherchild>
         </item1>
      </section>
      <section id="i">
         <item1 id="0" method="create"><!-- third consecutive create, BUT children have different value , so we don't remove this --><somechild>bbb</somechild>
         </item1>
         <item1 id="3" method="create">
            <other>xx</other>
         </item1>
         <item1 id="0" method="change">
            <otherchild>a</otherchild>
         </item1>
      </section>
   </nodeA>
</myroot>
```

Note, you can use this slightly varied style-sheet to assist in validation. Instead of removing the nodes, it annotates them to be removed by inserting a  node. Looking at the output of it helps to visualise what is going on.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[*]
         [deep-equal(.,
           preceding::*[name()=current()/name()]
                       [@id = current()/@id]
                       [../../@id = current()/../../@id]
                       [1])]" >
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
            <removed>
             <xsl:value-of select="'Parent of this node will be REMOVED.'" />
             <xsl:value-of select="../../@id" />
            </removed>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Sean: I think that you should test for ancestor node identity -- not just that name, id etc are the same.

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin in your solution you have `<xsl:template match="*[*]
         [deep-equal(.,..` can I know what is the `[*]` used for? what's the different with using just `*` ? Thanks

Comment: [*] discounts childless elements, that is to say the "leaves". There is an assumption behind it that the <item1> type nodes that you are testing for redundancy will never be leaf nodes. I don't know if this is really a correct assumption. Remember this came from your template, and by implication you put it there for a reason.

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin Hello, I just realized that the solutions does not take into accounts for sibling with the same id (ex. `section`). How to change it so that it will consider only sibling with the same id ? Thank you.